# Image is not loading from django rest framework in react

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

i am beginner in drf. i want to load image from django rest framework  to react but I does not show image in react.

**views.py**

```
def PostView(request):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,JSONParser)
    if request.method=="GET":
        post = Post.objects.all()
        post_serializer = PostSerializer(post, many=True)
        return Response(post_serializer.data)
```

**Seriliazer.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Axios call**

```
 async function getPost() {
    await axios
      .get(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/"
     
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setPost(res.data);
      });
  }
```

and react code is

```
<div className="card mb-3" key={res.id}>
          <img className="card-img-top" src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000${res.image}`} alt="post image" />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h4>{res.title}</h4>
            <p className="card-text">{res.image}</p>
          </div>
```

following is my API response
[following is my API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swunn.png)

and browser error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx5BA.png)

Comment: Have you configured your urls to serve media files during development? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: yes i configured. my url file `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: thanks @lain Shelvington i configured it i add serve media setting in with app level URL now its working with project level URL file

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass context into serializer. Thanks to that DRF will be add domain to image.

Change it to this

```py
post_serializer = PostSerializer(post, many=True, context={"request": request})
```

Comment: thanks, @sharpek for your reply I change it but still face the same error

Comment: thanks @sharpek your hint also supported me..

Answer (score 0):

change your p tag to `<img src={res.image}/>`, should do it if it was passing as a url